# What kind of tooth is this?

Tags: ocean, fossils

[image: possible fossilized shark tooth][image: tooth?][image: different angle][image: please help me identify]

Please help me identify this tooth and the era its from. I found it in Panama City Beach Florida. Its cold and hard when i bite it. It looks very old. Possibly a shark tooth?

Comment: Looks shark, but not sure.

Comment: You can check: https://www.wikihow.com/Identify-Shark-Teeth, I would say it might be Cosmopolitodus hastalis. One of the best resources is: http://www.fossilguy.com/sites/l_creek/lcrk_col_shark.htm

Comment: it is a shark tooth and you are holding it upsidedown,the pointy part is the top of the tooth.

Comment: I keep getting told on another site ,that its not a tooth at all,but possibly a fish bone segment shaped like a tooth,thats been tossed in the surf alot. This doesn't make much sense to me. As all the pictures i have found resemble this as an actual tooth. Not to mention,the thickness and coldness to it. I have never saw or even felt a bone like this. Even through numerous google searches. I believe its a tooth as well,but missing its enamel.

Comment: My msg continued due to being to long..The back side does have some weird lines,that makes it look like it was stuck onto something for a very long time before it broke off that. Up where the gum area is. Also on the back,there is a horizontal line that i see on many shark teeth with enamel. There is also a vertical line going down both sides.

Comment: You may want to search fossil fish scales.  Possibly more specifically fossilized gar scales.  Not sure if that's what it is though.

Comment: I looked up fossilized gar scales,I can see it possibly being one of those. :)

Comment: It could be several different things with something that small it is difficult to identify without a scope,  there are a number of things with that general shape and the detail is too hard to see in a picture. you can however take things like that to any natural history museums and they will generally identify them for free.

Answer (score -3):

It looks very much like a shark tooth, but it looks like it’s weathered and worn. It may have spent a good deal of time buried below the sand, being slowly ground by the sand and tide action. Eventually it became dislodged and after a while of being worn smoother it washed up and you found it.

Comment: Please don't encourage people to drill holes in fossils. Also you should include how you determine an identification.